# Streamreader file.Readline properly closing the stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream

Is this OK? (.Net 4.5)

```
try
{
    StreamReader sr = = new StreamReader(ValidFilePathName);
    line = file.ReadLine();
    While (line != null)
    {
        line = file.ReadLine();
    }
    sr.Close();
}
catch
{
    // blah Do nothing
}
```

I feel like there is something wrong with my pattern here. My concern is that when there is a file exception, does the stream get closed properly? I was taught to use using to set the stream, but Code Analysis tool does not like it. Perhaps there is something else. It seems to read the file OK, but I remember needing to use File stream and stream reader in the past... Was there a good reason for combining the two?

Comment: You need to close your stream in the `finally` block. Why does your code analysis tool not like the `using` statement?

Comment: I think it is when I use nested using statements where this code is not an example of that. So In the finally block... yes but that means I need to... OK I think I have it. Thanks.

Comment: So that means I also need to move the initialization of the SR outside the try block.

Comment: Yes. What tool do you use? Multiple using statements should be ok

Comment: Built in (VS 2013). "CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd831853(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: I guess you can ask a new question with the code that produces it to get some clarification on reasons behind usch behavior of the tool

Comment: Well I have researched and understand sort of... but not enough to defend or denounce it.

Comment: Did you have `sr.Close()` as well as the `using` construct? Or did you put in `Close` when you took out `using`?

Comment: no, separate implementations. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000136/using-statement-filestream-and-or-streamreader-visual-studio-2012-warnings (now that I have my answer I see the accepted answer there is the same... ish)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always need to dispose of objects in the `finally` close to ensure that they are disposed correctly.

```
StreamReader sr = null;
try
{
    sr = = new StreamReader(ValidFilePathName);
    line = file.ReadLine();
    While (line != null)
    {
        line = file.ReadLine();
    }
}
catch
{
    // blah Do nothing
}
finally
{
   if (sr != null)
   {
       sr.Close();
   }       
}
```

Comment: Error: Use of unassigned local variable SR in finally block. I can assign null at the first line?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the code. I've also included the check in the `finally` just in case `StreamReader` will not be initialized.

Answer (score 3):

I know there is already an accepted answer here, but have you ever utilized the `using` statement? This statement will automatically handle all of your disposal for you. And yes, it will take care of it on exceptions. Check out the link [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) and my example below.

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ValidFilePathName))
    {
        line = file.ReadLine();
        While (line != null)
        {
            line = file.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string myException = ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: That was where the re-factoring started... actually. CA2202 is a code analysis warning (starting 2012?). That warning does not like this way of disposing of idisposable objects. One can choose to ignore this warning. I am undecided my self, but I (secretly) wanted to be able to properly handle file access without the warning. I think this answer is highly useful as part of the conversation, and so +1 for that.

Comment: Interesting. I don't receive that warning when `using` it, but I will have to keep an eye out for sure. Never had any actual errors due to it, I know that much! Thanks for the +1 though!

Comment: You have to run the vs code analysis tool to get the warning. I think it is in vs2012, but it is definitely in vs2013. Of course I don't think it causes any errors. I think Microsoft is afraid of idisaposable objects being written or overridden poorly.